# Is it OK in Astro to pass the whole .md frontmatter through layouts and components?

Tags: reactjs, react-props, astrojs

When I need attributes from the frontmatter of a .md here and there (in layouts, base layouts, components…) I use `Astro.props`.

But sometimes it is very tedious to create individual values to be passed, mostly during the development process, because it is usual to add, remove, and rename properties.

I presume that Astro.props are passed as references, no as full content, so I wonder if it is OK to pass just the whole frontmatter (`data`, in V2). This way each component or layout can take whatever it needs from the .md frontmatter.

It works perfectly, of course, and now, with the schemas I do not need to declare interfaces, but I wonder if this can be considered a bad practice when things get bigger.

```
<SomeLayout title = {item.data.title} author = {item.data.author} topMenuLabel = {item.data.label}>
```

Vs

```
<SomeLayout allTheFrontmatter = {item.data}>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is ok, you can do whatever works best for you

Also, instead of writing the props manually you can spread them like this:

```
<Layout {...item.data} />
```